# How can I capture packets not addressed to the device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to find out how use Android's `multicastlock` for capturing packets not addressed to the device. As I understand [the SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html), I can capture them.

How can I capture them, or how can I use `multicastlock`?